# How to close associations foreign key dropdown in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp, view, model

i got 2 table .
User and Group, User belongsTo Group. 
Group had 3 data =  `1 => admin, 2 => users, 3 =>leaders`
As we use the cake bake console .
it generate add/edit/view/index file automatically.

OK, now the question is in my User controller, between `add & edit` actions, there got set compact which making `group_id` become drop down in view files.

Now i want disable the dropdown list in add view file, which i want restrict the the group_id field also be 3. Similar as `$this->Form->input('group_id', array('value' => 1, 'disabled' => disabled'));`

Is this possible ? any ways to close the associations in add Form ?

Comment: you just want to group_id 3 in dropdown, right ?

Comment: How to disabled select: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_disabled.asp, You cannot disabled options in select input

Comment: i know how its be disabled ... but anyway to make the field become input rather than select dropdown ?